# Oracle trigger efficiency vs scheduled jobs

Tags: oracle

Certain invalid characters sometimes get inserted into database due to improper keyboard configuration of end-users.

We have a pl/sql script that iterates through all columns and replaces the invalid characters. The script takes less than one minute to complete (but our system is still beta and is not used widely) .

One solution is to create a trigger that replaces the invalid characters right before insertion into the tables and one solution would be using a scheduled job to run the so-called script.

Which one is more efficient ?

Comment: Why can't you filter it at the Data Entry Level?

Comment: I think it would be faster if we do it on database level. Additionally, in that case we have to use java string replace methods on every data that user enters. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I've seen this situation many times.  Its an app issue, not a data issue.  The app programmers allow some generic text box with no filters/checks and dump whatever into the db.  Its found sometime later and, because its already in the db, its instantly a "data" problem.  EvilTeach is right, go upstream and find the source of the problem (the data entry level on app side).

Comment: I suspect you are incorrect danrah.  You literally have people keying data.  There are a lot of microseconds between keystrokes.  That should be plenty of time, to do a little bit of filtering, or perhaps even pop up a message that the terminal is misconfigured.

Comment: @EvilTeach I agree with you but in that case we must add the validation code to hundreds of text boxes to check for invalid character entry. But only 5% of users have misconfigured keyboards. Furthermore, we have dynamically generated fields that make the validation process a little bit harder. After 12 years of working on this project, we have a tangled web here and we are looking for a simple solution(a very simple trigger, or a scheduled script?) !

Comment: Interesting approach.  Put a band-aid on it without doing anything to stop the bleeding.

Comment: The bleeding has to do with incorrect standards set for the farsi keyboard on different OS versions, again as I said if there is a way to override the behavior of all html input tags then the problem can be solved upstream.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a scheduled job, there is still some time during which the invalid characters are inside your data. If it is very important that this is not the case, use a trigger. A trigger will ensure that the database only contains valid characters.

I don't think efficiency is very important here. A trigger can easily keep up with data entry by users.

Comment: Btw. can these characters appear in every column? How about numeric columns? In the trigger you can only check columns that are prone to contain these invalid characters.

Comment: Fortunately, we have some filters that restrict the columns. Only Clob and Varchar2 columns in tables that begin with 'CD' or 'PN'

Answer (score 1):

Not a fan of triggers, to be honest.

You could improve the efficiency of a scheduled job by providing an index that identifies the rows that need to be updated.

In general the syntax would be something like:

```
create index my_speshul_index on my_table(
  case when some_expression then 1 else null end);
```

some_expression is the expression that detects the presence of these characters -- possibly a regexp_like.

Then you would query:

```
select ... from my_table
where case when some_expression then 1 else null end;
```

Comment: But in this case, the invalid characters are inserted to database and remain there until the job is run ( For at least one day).

Comment: Unless you schedule it to run every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go would be to allow the data to enter the database as originally typed, but create a virtual column that would contain the cleaned data.

However, that's only workable if the problem is limited to a few columns. Since it can be all user-enterable columns, a trigger with regexp_replace seems to be the best way to go. Depending on what characters you allow, it could be as simple as a series of statements like

```
 :new.columnA := regexp_replace(:new.ColumnA,'[^[:print:]]','');
```

That is, just remove all the non-printable characters.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is not limited to a few columns. This problem occurs in all Clobs and Varchar2s